# Need info on UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, ios4

I know you can have multiple components in a picker view but is there a way to make it so they all turn together? Sort of like having columns really. I don't want them to turn independantly from each other.

Comment: Why do you want multiple components, then? (I'm pretty sure) there are ways to add arbitrary views to the rows of the picker, so whatever you're trying to display, there should be a way.

Comment: I need to show 4 different values for 1 item. I could do it a different way but was wanting to use a picker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that's an easy one: instead of making a picker with 3 components, like day month and year, make a picker with one component consisting of a string for each day like `Sep 9 2011`.

Comment: Well duh, why didn't I think of that? Thanks. I was trying  to come up with some difficult solution when there didn't need to be.